# Google App Engine: NoClassDefFoundError on run

Tags: google-app-engine

Everytime I try to run my project, I get the following error message:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/util/Logging
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:82)**

What could be the problem? I've tried reinstalling Eclipse and reconfiguring the Build Path for a couple of times now, but no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: is this happening on your local machine, or in the app engine server farm?

Comment: @Peter Recore I am getting the same problem each time I am adding a lib.  Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am getting the same problem on eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Try running you're build (war directory) manually via the [dev_server script](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html) to determine if it's an Eclipse problem or a general classpath issue (that you're missing the required JAR).

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and running the dev_server script yielded the same result as running it via Eclipse.  It seems odd that the project is compiling just fine if I'm missing one of the required JARs - is there some way I could have wound up with a discrepancy between the set of JARs used for build and the set of JARs used to run?  How would I debug that?

Comment: When the program compiles it only needs to have the JARs in the classpath necessary to resolve the symbols for compilation.  It doesn't need all the JARs that runtime does.  For example if your class uses A in A.jar and A uses class B in B.jar you only need A.jar on the classpath to compile your class.  However at runtime you need A.jar and B.jar.  This is why your code compiles OK, but you get ClassNotFoundException at runtime.

Comment: I've uploaded a findclass bash script that you can use to search a dir of JARs for a given class.  Use it to find the JAR containing your missing class and then see if that JAR is on your classpath correctly.  https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6Kxr521e8HxZjlhM2EzMzYtYjdjZS00YWM3LWI2YmEtNzcwM2ZiMzliNDBi&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

See [ClassNotFoundException using Google App Engine for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464997/classnotfoundexception-using-google-app-engine-for-java/7465893#7465893) - at least one cause for this behavior was identified here.  It turns out JARs may *not* be under any subdirectory of war/WEB-INF/lib, regardless of whether you have the correct path to them in your classpath - they must be directly under war/WEB-INF/lib.

(Note: if you find that solves your problem, remember to upvote that gentleman's answer there, not my answer here.)

Comment: How to do this? I have inherited a maven project build in intellij and I have absolutely no knowledge about maven whatsever or war files.