# Hit Into ClassNotFoundException With Google CustomSearch

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to use [Google CustomSeach API java client](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/libraries). However upon running it I hit into an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
```

I have read that some said it is due to Guava library. However Guava is included in this project. Below is the print screen of referenced library used in this project:

[image]

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
        Customsearch cs = new Customsearch(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
        Customsearch.Cse.List list = cs.cse().list("rashidi zin");
        list.setKey(API_KEY);
        list.setCx(ID);

        Search results = list.execute();
```

I have been trying to add libraries such as apache http-client however it still doesn't work. Am I using the library incorrectly?

Comment: This question seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464997/classnotfoundexception-using-google-app-engine-for-java  Give that answer a try.

Comment: I tried removing what could be redundant dependencies but the error still persists.